# i have two tables (membership & persons). i want to get each name of a person with their highest order of position

Tags: mysql, sql

persons table

```
id name
1  boyax
2  lexan
3  joe
4  buten
5  milo
```

Membership table

```
id  position
1   president
1   chief-clerk
1   asst-secretary
1   book-keeper
2   asst-secretary
2   book-keeper
3   book-keeper
3   chief-clerk
3   asst-secretary
4   book-keeper
4   asst-secretary
4   president
4   chief-clerk
5   chief-clerk
5   asst-secretary
```

the membership sorted by : `1. president, 2. chief-clerk, 3. asst-secretary and 4. booker-keeper`

i tried with this approach:

```
select id, name , position from persons
left join membership on membership.id = persons.id group by persons.id
```

result should be:

```
id name    position
1  boyax   president
2  lexan   asst-secretary
3  joe     chief-clerk
4  buten   president
5  milo    chief-clerk
```

any idea is highly appreciated.

Comment: what error you got?

Comment: try an inner join rather then a left join and dont do any group by

Comment: i want to get unique id  per position sir.

Comment: try inner join once

Comment: i already tried but the position i need for each person doesn't come up well.

Comment: are there any more columns to the tables?

Comment: i want to get president for boyax which is the highest position from membership. and lexan should be ass-secretary which higher than book-keeper :(

Comment: membership : id, position, company

Comment: what about the persons table? what are the columns there?

Comment: persons - id, name, dob, address, telno

Comment: how come one id has 2 positions attached to it?



You need another column to join along with the id. Is there a third table which has similar columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try below query -

```
SELECT id, name, position
FROM(SELECT id, name, position, MAX(POS)
     FROM(select id, name, position, CASE WHEN position = 'president' THEN 1
                                          WHEN position = 'chief-clerk' THEN 2
                                          WHEN position = 'asst-secretary' THEN 3
                                          WHEN position = 'booker-keeper' THEN 4 END POS
          from persons
          left join membership on membership.id = persons.id
         ) T
          group by id, name, position
    ) TEMP
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir..Great,  i've got what i need :D

Comment: You are being over generous by calling me Sir. BTW, You're most welcome.